# TypeScript: is it possible to rewrite this helper type using interace

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I came across this helper type when reading this blog post https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-component-patterns/

```
type WithChildren<T = {}> = 
  T & { children?: React.ReactNode };

type CardProps = WithChildren<{
  title: string;
}>;
```

and we can use this type by doing the following

```
function Card({ title, children }: CardProps) {
  return <>
    <h1>{ title }</h1>
    {children}
  </>
}
```

My question is, is it possible to rewrite this type helper using `interface`?

Comment: It depends on the type. Your `WithChildren<T>` cannot be an interface because it would require writing `interface WithChildren<T = {}> extends T {children: React.ReactNode}` and an interface cannot extend its own type argument. The second type is fine however: `interface CardProps extends WithChildren<{}> { title: string; }` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simply combine the types to make one interface like so:

```js
interface CardProps {
    title: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}
```

Comment: in this case, is there any advantage of using one over the other i.e. type vs. interface?

Comment: generally you can more extend interfaces, and have classes implement interfaces, and interfaces can be merged, but if you're not doing any of that in this case, there's no real advantage one way or the other

Answer (score 0):

Adding `children` to your own interface seems like not the best idea for me, I find using `React.FC<Props>` generic much more convenient. You can pass your own interface into it and children will be automatically added as well

Here's example how to use `React.FC` type with arrow functions:
https://medium.com/@ethan_ikt/react-stateless-functional-component-with-typescript-ce5043466011

Comment: yea but that's exactly what the author of the blog post is advising against. He thinks that we should set children explicitly so he doesn't use React.FC. But it is his opinion at the end of the day. I am not trying to get a definitive answer here. I wanted to know if this can be reimplemented using `interface`

Comment: I see. So I agree with @frozen on this one then. About interfaces vs types I personally find types a lot more convenient to use with redux when you are taking a component-based approach. But you can find a lot of posts on the internet about `interfaces vs types` topic, mostly there's no real difference, pick one that is more convenient to you